# MySqlException - Access denied for user: MySQL, ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using `NET Core 2.1` and `MySQL` with installed `MySql.Data`.
This is `appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
     "DefaultConnectionString": 
        "server=localhost;port=3306;database=database_name;user=root;password=password"
}
```

And `Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddDbContext<CardsContext>(options =>

  options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")));
```

The entire app is simple scaffold CRUD application, but when I try to access some of the `GET` routes like `/api/persons/5`, I am getting this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   MySqlException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
>
> MySqlException: Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'card_root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex)

I am sure, that this is the configuration, because i can connect with PHP with the same user/pass/database/port/host

Comment: Is the service running?  First run from PHP and check Task Manager to see that service is started.  Then repeat using c#.  Next verify there is a TCP connection listening on port 3306 from cmd.exe >Netstat -a

Comment: Can you provide the user accounts information?